# How to convert the date July 1, 2017 to dd-MM-yyyy using Hive SQL?

Tags: hive, hiveql, date-formatting

I have a Hive table with a Week column having values such as:

[image: Date Column in hive table]

I have to convert this field to a date format such as: 2017-07-01  (yyyy-MM-dd) using hive SQL.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of `unix_timestamp` and `from_unixtime`

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(week,'MMMM dd, yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd') from table_name;
```

`unix_timestamp(string datetime, string pattern)` converts datetime with given pattern to unix time stamp.

`from_unixtime(bigint unixtime[, string format])` converts the number of seconds from unix epoch.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `from_unixtime` and `unix_timestamp`.

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(weekCol,'MMM dd, yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```